# Plot data values inside pie charts slice

Tags: highcharts, slice, pie-chart

How to add a data values inside the slice in pie chart. Can any one help me in this? whether this is possible?

Comment: This post might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235666/highcharts-pie-chart-add-text-inside-each-slice/29063822#29063822

Answer (score 29):

You can use datalalabels - distance parameter : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.distance

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-datalabels-distance/

```
  plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                distance: -30,
                color: 'white'
            }
        }
    },
```