# highcharts pie dynamic label inside and outside for each slice

Tags: highcharts, label, pie-chart

I am working on a pie chart with a smaller display area of around 250*250 and willing to utilize the available space wisely as the labels are taking most of the space and reducing the actual pie size.

Is it possible to render labels inside/outside of the pie based on data for each slices. for example in the classic browser share example, if the Firefox is at 45%, I want to be rendered inside the pie (distance -40 may be) and where the slice is less such as Opera at 6% - I want it to be shown outside with a connector.

Comment: Live example will be helpful for us

Comment: @user1251323 do you want similar like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235666/highcharts-pie-chart-add-text-inside-each-slice/29063822#29063822 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can define only general [distance](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.distance) for labels.