# Multiple labels in Highcharts Pie Graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts pie graph that I need to show multiple labels for each slice, such as an indicator (title) label with a connector on the outside of the slice, and a percentage label without connectors inside the slice.

I can set the distance property in order to bring the label (and the connector) to inside part of the slice but then, of course, there is no label outside anymore.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) which allows to add custom text / labels / paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct possibility to create multiple dataLabels. As you can see on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488813/highcharts-pie-datalabels-inside-and-outside), a solution would be to create two overlaying charts.
See [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4RKF4/29/) :

```
        $(function () {
            // Create the chart
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'pie',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                    y:100

                },
                title: {
                    text: 'sfs '
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: ' '
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
//                        y:1,
                        shadow: false,
//                        center: ['50%', '50%'],
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        showInLegend: false,
                        size: '80%',
                        innerSize: '60%'
                      ,

                        data: [
                            ['allo', 18],
                            ['asdad', 14],
                            ['asdad', 11],
                            ['asdasd', 10],
                            ['adad', 8],
                            ['asdada', 7],
                            ['adada ada', 7],
                            ['adad', 5],
                            ['asdas',7],
                            ['ada', 3]

                        ]
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '%'
                },
                series: [
                    {
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Browser share',

                        dataLabels: {
                            color:'white',
                            distance: -20,
                            formatter: function () {
                                if(this.percentage!=0)  return Math.round(this.percentage)  + '%';

                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Browser share',

                        dataLabels: {
                            connectorColor: 'grey',
                            color:'black',
//                            y:-10,
                            softConnector: false,
                            connectorWidth:1,
                            verticalAlign:'top',
                            distance: 20,
                            formatter: function () {
                                if(this.percentage!=0)  return this.point.name;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
```